# In android studio(Java) + tflite. if I classify an image that i didn't trained in my model, in app it still shows a result

Tags: java, android-studio, model, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

In android studio Java, i have imported my trained model and I get codes in Github (Image Classification) and it works but my problem was:

The list/name i have trained : sunflower, rose etc.

I classify an image of chair that is not i have trained in my model but still it shows a result like "sunflower". Please help me I want my image classification to be accurate.

```
buclassify.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        int imageTensorIndex = 0;
        int[] imageShape = tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).shape(); // {1, height, width, 3}
        imageSizeY = imageShape[1];
        imageSizeX = imageShape[2];
        DataType imageDataType = tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType();

        int probabilityTensorIndex = 0;
        int[] probabilityShape =
                tflite.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).shape(); // {1, NUM_CLASSES}
        DataType probabilityDataType = tflite.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).dataType();

        inputImageBuffer = new TensorImage(imageDataType);
        outputProbabilityBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(probabilityShape, probabilityDataType);
        probabilityProcessor = new TensorProcessor.Builder().add(getPostprocessNormalizeOp()).build();

        inputImageBuffer = loadImage(bitmap);

        tflite.run(inputImageBuffer.getBuffer(),outputProbabilityBuffer.getBuffer().rewind());
        showresult();

    });


  private TensorImage loadImage(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    // Loads bitmap into a TensorImage.
    inputImageBuffer.load(bitmap);

    // Creates processor for the TensorImage.
    int cropSize = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    // TODO(b/143564309): Fuse ops inside ImageProcessor.
    ImageProcessor imageProcessor =
            new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                    .add(new ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(cropSize, cropSize))
                    .add(new ResizeOp(imageSizeX, imageSizeY, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
                    .add(getPreprocessNormalizeOp())
                    .build();
    return imageProcessor.process(inputImageBuffer);
}



    private TensorOperator getPreprocessNormalizeOp() {
    return new NormalizeOp(IMAGE_MEAN, IMAGE_STD);
}
private TensorOperator getPostprocessNormalizeOp(){
    return new NormalizeOp(PROBABILITY_MEAN, PROBABILITY_STD);
}



   private void showresult(){

    try{
        labels = FileUtil.loadLabels(this,"labels.txt");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Map<String, Float> labeledProbability =
            new TensorLabel(labels, probabilityProcessor.process(outputProbabilityBuffer))
                    .getMapWithFloatValue();
    float maxValueInMap =(Collections.max(labeledProbability.values()));

    for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : labeledProbability.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue()==maxValueInMap) {
            classitext.setText(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
}


    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
        bitmap = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(data).getExtras()).get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    if(requestCode==12 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
        imageuri = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageuri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: I have added all the codes that is related in image classification sir.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if you send an image to be predicted by model, it will classify it, looking for the nearest class possible as the trained classes. It will not refuse or show it doesn't match any flower if you don't program it.

Hence, you need to add a function that return the result is "unknown" if the probability for all class is less than the `threshold` you defined. Multi class classification NN usually uses `softmax` for the activation at output layer, so you may need to set the minimum probability for the max probability class. You can do it like this:

```java
float minProbabilityThreshold = 0.65; // Set the threshold here.
for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : labeledProbability.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue()==maxValueInMap && maxValueInMap > minProbabilityThreshold) {
            classitext.setText(entry.getKey());
        } else {
            classitext.setText('Unknown image');
        }
    }
```

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH MADAM, YOUR'E AWESOME !! <3
Ma'am can I ask one last time please? My if statement doesn't work on my onclicklistener. I want to get the value of textView(classitext) and if it is true it will open a new activity.

```
  pagatpat.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (classitext.equals("Pagatpat")){
                openPagatpat();
            }
        });
```

**--------------------------**

```
    private void openPagatpat(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PagatpatInfo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }

```

Comment: You need to do `classiText.getText().toString().equals("Pagatpat")` to check the value. However I am not a woman. **Please upvote my answer and click the tick besides my answer if you find this helpful on solving your problem.**